# Why is my RapidSSL Certificate chain is not trusted on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, socket

I have a website that works perfectly with Chrome & other browser but i get some errors with PHP in CLI mode so i'm investigating it, running this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 32 -connect dev.carlipa-online.com:443
```

Quite suprisingly my HTTPS appears untrusted with a `Verify return code: 27 (certificate not trusted)` Here is the raw output :

```
verify depth is 32
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 serialNumber = khKDXfnS0WtB8DgV0CAdsmWrXl-Ia9wZ, C = FR, O = *.carlipa-online.com, OU = GT44535187, OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12, OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = *.carlipa-online.com
verify return:1
```

So `GeoTrust Global CA` appears to be not trusted on the system (Ubuntu 11.10). Added `Equifax_Secure_CA` to try to solve this... But i get in this case `Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)` !

Raw output :

```
verify depth is 32
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "GeoTrust, Inc.", CN = RapidSSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 serialNumber = khKDXfnS0WtB8DgV0CAdsmWrXl-Ia9wZ, C = FR, O = *.carlipa-online.com, OU = GT44535187, OU = See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12, OU = Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN = *.carlipa-online.com
verify return:1
```

#### Edit

Looks like my server does not trust/provide the Equifax Root CA, however i do correctly have the file in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Equifax...`

Comment: Are you specifying a `-CAfile` or `-CApath` in your `openssl` command?  Is your server presenting the full trust chain (as validated by your Chrome client that trusts the cert)?

Comment: Yes, the server does present the correct (given by RapidSSL chain). Looks like my Ubuntu Server does not trust Equifax. Don't know why.

Comment: It's not presenting the full chain (there's no Equifax certificate in there), see my answer.  Does the validate work when you set `-CApath /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` in your `openssl` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like GeoTrust has done some re-jiggering of their signing structure.

The third certificate that you're presenting (per Raj's answer) is this one:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But when I open your certificate with a Windows client, the chain resolves to this one:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

These two certificates share common cryptography (so they'll both verify for the subordinate's signature), but the one you're presenting is signed by that Equifax certificate, while the one that Windows decides the trust chain leads to is signed by Equifax.

Since you're presenting the certificate that is signed by Equifax instead of the self-signed one, you're not presenting the full chain.  Add the Equifax certificate to the chain that your web server is presenting:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now, that may or may not resolve the trust issues with your `openssl` command line client - you'll need to make sure that it's properly finding your system's store of trusted roots; you can use `-CApath` to make sure that it's pointing to the correct location.

Comment: I've tried that but i get `Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)` error in this case.

Comment: What did you try?  You need to correct your chain issues and make sure `openssl` gets the correct path.  What changes have you made?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-CApath RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem`:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 32 -CApath RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem -connect www.example.org:443
```

Download the [RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem here](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/RapidSSL%20Intermediate/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem).

Answer (score 0):

Posting in answer instead of comments as this is too big for comment. Don't have ubuntu to test with right at this moment, but chain looks complete from my redhat server(rhel 5 update 3):

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect dev.carlipa-online.com:443

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
verify return:1
depth=0 /serialNumber=khKDXfnS0WtB8DgV0CAdsmWrXl-Ia9wZ/C=FR/O=*.carlipa-online.com/OU=GT44535187/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.carlipa-online.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=khKDXfnS0WtB8DgV0CAdsmWrXl-Ia9wZ/C=FR/O=*.carlipa-online.com/OU=GT44535187/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.carlipa-online.com
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/serialNumber=khKDXfnS0WtB8DgV0CAdsmWrXl-Ia9wZ/C=FR/O=*.carlipa-online.com/OU=GT44535187/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.carlipa-online.com
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3849 bytes and written 316 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 16DC3DA9B3EB1CE1E17D6B3E7AFDCDBB8579E91C53FC31E227187E5BBDFD80D4
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 0AC0914E228A536FF7455C17E175E4F657E12278D0994CEC24C44469BF9A4D21910C4FAA0253BE608617702FA408C399
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1337702247
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: So it looks like my ubuntu does not have the Equifax root CA installed, any idea how i could fix that?